# Use Nutiteq base engine API for rendering 3d map, free commercial use

Tags: android, android-mapview, nutiteq

My question is simple, I wonder if I could use **nutiteq API** in my android app with a **free licence membership key** (which is required to render MapView), download map tiles from other free wms sources (such as OSM) and still be able to use the API for **commercial purposes for free**?
I came down to the following link when searching for an answer to my question:
https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Free-openstreetmap-license

If not possible, what would be another alternative for 3d map rendering API/Library to be used for both commercial and personal cases in android?

Answer (score 0):

For Nutiteq you would need enterprise license for this kind of commercial uses. We have invested years of our effort developing it, so asking everything for free sounds quite weird from a software developer who does provides commercial projects. What about free Google Maps?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have to disagree on the comment that my question was "weird" as a developer etc. You by all means must have stumbled upon a situation where you were obligated to see if the package you are using in your project is usable for your purpose or not (Does Mapsforge ring any bells?). This is what I am exactly doing here. Why would checking the usage policy of a library should be reckoned weird or objectified in a harsh tone? I like nutiteq project as a whole and if there was a one time payment for the library without monthly subscription complications, i would consider it

Comment: We actually have one-time license options also - you can ask from licensing@nutiteq.com

Comment: p.s. by "weird" I refer that you ask 3 times free things for your *commercial project*. I suspect that there is money for the project, but you still expect to use other's work/services for free. That's not really good long term plan. Mapsforge is actually a good example - no-one paid and funded the project, now the original developer works somewhere else, development and support are very slow and you get free product which is practically not usable for serious (commercial) projects. You can't base commercial projects on free stuff like that.